# Why did Igneel not attack Acnologia on Tenrou Island?

Tags: fairy-tail

For those who have read the Tartaros Arc.

> In the Tartaros Arc we learn that the Dragons were hiding within the Dragon Slayers since the year 777. Hence, why Natsu and Gajeel could not leave the guild during the battle of Fairy Tail. We learn that they were hiding to build antibodies to prevent Dragon Slayers to turn into Dragons once again and were waiting for a moment to defeat Acnologia. Yet they had their chance to defeat Acnologia on Tenrou Island. Why did they not seize their chance then and there? With Makarov, Gildartz, Laxus around, they would have had a much better chance of defeating him. So why did they not attack on Tenrou Island?

Comment: The latest chapter revealed that the amount of magic required to put a dent in acnologia is pretty absurd.

Comment: @ton.yeung That doesnt explain why igneel wanted to fight him alone during tartaros, but not together during tenrou island. It would make more sense to fight him together seeing how strong he is. Btw igneel ripped off his arm on his own. Imagine makarov holding him down like he did with igneel on top of him.

Comment: hmm.. I seem to have a different impression of the circumstances around the tartaros arc. Yes, I know I'm being vague.

Comment: @ton.yeung how is it different?

Comment: Probably because it was in Tenrou Island, the holy place of Fairy Tail. There might be some form of magic that prevented him from acting.

Comment: Hmmm... im not sure but at Tenrou Island all Fairy members werent so strong as now, l8ter when dragons attack at Grand Magic no1 could do anything to dragon (except Dragon Slayers a bit slow them down, but did nothing more) so i think Fairy members could not help Igneel that much as you think :)

Comment: @Buzka91 You are forgetting that during Tenrou also the other dragons could help. Igneel, Grandeeney and Metalicana could all together attack Acnologia. And seeing at what speed Grandeeney flew over the continent, the other dragons could come and join. But during Tartaros, nobody could help Igneel. He was all alone. He was also much weaker because 7 more years had passed. So he actually had a much better chance to attack Acnologia 7 years ago, so why did he not do it then, and why did he attack now?

Comment: @PeterRaeves When dragon came from Eclipse Gate wasnt something said about only Igneel got _ANY_ chances VS. Acnologia? I wasnt reading manga at Tartaros (only few chapters) so i cant think anything else :) maybe in these 7 year gap Dragons still were able to create antibodies for their Dragon Slayers? I think that would make any sense, but i believe it cant be proven... :(

Answer (score 1):

Because the dragons inside dragon slayer's bodies were waiting for The Dragon King festival as that would be the time for them to take action and by then enough antibodies would have generated to prevent Dragon Slayers form turning into dragons

Source : Fairy Tail Manga Chapter 400 Pages 12-18 and
Tartaros arc summary in http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Igneel#Synopsis

Comment: Do you have any sources to back this statement up? here at A&M we prefer answers based upon facts. You can take the [tour](http://anime.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a bit more familiar with our ways.

Comment: You can read up Natsu and Igneel's conversation when he is fighting Acnologia. Also there is a summary of that here http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Igneel

Comment: Please include this information into your answer using the [edit](http://anime.stackexchange.com/posts/36366/edit) function. If your source is the conversation between igneel while fighting acnologia, it wouldn't hurt to include the chapter number/page number as well. As for the link. If you are including it, please also include the relevant information from the page in your answer. :)

Answer (score -1):

Well, in my opinion, because the other dragons of Rogue and Sting (Skiadrum & Weisslogia) weren't really "around" I should say. And they didn't make enough antibodies for them to make sure that they themselves wouldn't turn into dragons themselves. It's not the best answer, but at least it's something right ? :)